# How do I access the ATTRIBUTE of a Foreign Key Object in another Model?

Tags: django, database, django-models

```
class doctorMaster(models.Model):

    doctorID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    doctorName = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    doctorDesignation = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    doctorSpecialization = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    UpdatedOn = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.doctorID)



class SMSlookup(models.Model):
    recordID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    doctorID = models.OneToOneField(doctorMaster,on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_field='doctorID')
    doctorName = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    SMSContact = models.IntegerField (null = False)
    UpdatedOn = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.doctorID)
```

I need to be able to access doctorID of the first model using its namesake in the second.

How should doctorID be defined for this to be possible?